# Raycaster: Line Precision Becomes Very Low when Having More Points

Tags: three.js

I'm using `THREE.Raycaster` to do `THREE.Line` picking. When my `THREE.Line` contains more points, the precision becomes very low. Changing the `THREE.Raycaster.linePrecision` doesn't work.

Is that caused by the super big bounding sphere? But in this [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interact#webgl_interactive_lines), the lines contain 50 points and work well.

So what's the problem?

Comment: Well, if the original example works as expected, maybe there's a problem in your code. Would you mind to show us what you have?

Comment: @JuanFerrer My code is too complicated. What's the idea of intersection testing when the line contains lots of points?